# Finding a hidden Button

Tags: c#, button, directx-9

I played in the past on partypoker and worte my own window arranger. it arranged the windows based on a visible button, but today i switched to a different room.

the problem is that i cant find the button with **spy++**. spy++ **doesnt recognize** that there is a button.  some buttons are findable with spy++, but not the one i need

any ideas how i can find this hidden button ?

Comment: I wrote a poker bot once with Paradise Poker, then they changed the GUI! I saw someone's else's program that did the same thing except it worked of network packets - in hindsight I wish I'd done it that way. My program took screen shots and identified cards and suits and clicked Fold, Call or Bet based on a point strategy system. I would suggest taking a screenshot but what if they change the design? what if they recompile the app and the window Handle address changes? I didn't down vote you btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the button is not an actual button (i.e., if it's drawn through code rather than using the standard Win32 button control) you're not going to be able to find it with Spy++. It won't be an actual window, so it won't have a window handle. Thus, you're also not going to be able to click it through the normal mechanisms, like sending it a `BM_CLICK` message.

It's possible that they're doing this as a security feature, but it's also quite likely that this is part of the growing trend away from using the native UI controls, one that I very strongly disagree with and whose motivations I seriously question.

Your only hope is probably UI automation, which is very tricky to get right. Make sure to test the program in a virtual machine so the world doesn't end when you inevitably click the wrong thing accidentally.

Comment: thank you, that helped me alot. but i dont have to click a button , i need to check if is visible to maximize the window. i got it working because i used the betslider instead of the check/call button but if someone goes all in there is no betslider anymore and than am screwed. anyways this helps me a lot thank you